# How to remove domain flag in Nginx proxy configuration?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

So, I know about [proxy_cookie_domain](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cookie_domain). Is it possible to use this to remove the domain flag altogether? I've tried

- `proxy_cookie_domain .example.com;` - error
- `proxy_cookie_domain .example.com "";` - results in `Domain=.`
- `proxy_cookie_domain .example.com null;` -results in `Domain=.null`

I just want to remove the domain altogether.